# How to pause for specific amount of time? (Excel/VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet that has the following macro.  I'd like to loop it every second but danged if I can find the function to do that.  Isn't it possible?

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Do
    Calculate
    'Here I want to wait for one second

Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use the [Wait method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213656%28office.11%29.aspx):

```
Application.Wait Now + #0:00:01#
```

or (for Excel 2010 and later):

```
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that, but I speculate you want `DoEvents` as demoed here http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/06/14/stopwatch/

Comment: your link is password protected.

Comment: @Benoit and @Keng, you can put 1 second directly, avoiding to transform text to date. Is more clean for me: 
`Application.Wait(Now + #0:00:01#)`
Cheers!

Comment: That format wasn't working in Excel 2010. This works though : `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))`

Comment: @BenS What If I want the function to wait for less 1 second?

Comment: DateAdd("s", 1, Now) does the right thing. And can be generalized for any long number of seconds: DateAdd("s", nSec, Now) without using the time literal. To sleep less than 1 second use the Sleep API in kernel32

Comment: @ZX9 timevalue("00:00:01") = 0.0000115740...  So Application.wait(now + 0.00001) is about a second.  I like to use `Application.wait(now + 1e-5)` for a second, `Application.wait(now + 0.5e-5)` for half a second etc.

Comment: This solution is not precise, it does not take in account the milliseconds that already elapsed from current time... For example, if there is only 1 milisecond left until the Now seconds changes, you will only sleep for 1 milisecond.

Comment: This method has several drawbacks: 1) It only works in Excel. 2) It causes the application to become unresponsive to user input, essentially "freeze". 3) Its time resolution is limited to one second. Look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457) for a cross-platform, cross-app solution that doesn't freeze the application and doesn't cause excessive CPU usage.

Answer (score 65):

Add this to your module

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Or, for 64-bit systems use:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
```

Call it in your macro like so:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Do
    Calculate
    Sleep 1000   ' delay 1 second

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use the VBA method to do this rather than using kernel32.dll?

Comment: I have used this method as it is portable between the various office products such as Access and is not Excel specific.

Comment: There is also another VBA application (ERS) that I use that has a _very_ limited subset of the language.

Comment: +1, because `Sleep()` lets you specify wait times of less than 1 second. `Application.Wait` is sometimes too granular.

Comment: @JulianKnight: `Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)`

Comment: Is this work for Mac? However in this method user can't do any work in excel while it is paused.

Comment: Mac is different as it doesn't use "kernel32" You can call a wait using MacScript, which is no longer supported for 2016. `MacScript("delay(0.1)")` works for Excel 2011, and will be 1/10th second.

Comment: This sometimes locks up Excel after several iterations. Any ideas?

Comment: This method has several drawbacks: 1) It only works on Windows. 2) It causes the application to stop responding ("Not responding" in Task Manager). Look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457) for a cross-platform, cross-app solution that doesn't freeze the application and doesn't cause excessive CPU usage.

Answer (score 50):

instead of using:

```
Application.Wait(Now + #0:00:01#)
```

i prefer:

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
```

because it is a lot easier to read afterwards.

Comment: And it works whereas, in Office 2013, the #0:0:1# format converts to 1 second after midnight.

Comment: WARNING: All solutions using 'Application.Wait' have 1 second imprecision. This method does not consider the milliseconds that already elapsed since the current second started... For example, if there is only 1 milisecond left until the time seconds change, you will only sleep for 1 milisecond. You are just comparing 2 rounded numbers instead of waiting for 1 second!

Answer (score 23):

this works flawlessly for me. insert any code before or after the "do until" loop. In your case, put the 5 lines (time1= & time2= & "do until" loop) at the end inside your do loop

```
sub whatever()
Dim time1, time2

time1 = Now
time2 = Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Do Until time1 >= time2
        DoEvents
        time1 = Now()
    Loop

End sub
```

Comment: I like this solution most because I didn't want to halt the message queue.

Comment: This solution is precise and does not require the declaration of the sleep-API-Function. I used to store time in double values and use microseconds instead with the same result.

Comment: This solution works better than the similar solutions below that use `Timer` because the `Timer` approach fails just before midnight.

Comment: This solution is not precise, it does not take in account the milliseconds that already elapsed from current time... For example, if there is only 1 milisecond left until the Now seconds changes, you will only sleep for 1 milisecond.

Comment: when other solutions were taking a long time for a non-MS Office based VBA macro, this one worked perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 17):

## Complete Guide to Pausing VBA Execution

##### Background Information and Explanation

All Microsoft Office applications run VBA code in the same thread as the main user interface. This means, as long as the VBA code doesn't call `DoEvents`, code execution freezes the entire application (It will show as "not responding" in Task-Manager!). This includes calls to the `Sleep` API function. Once `Sleep` is called, there is no way of recovering from this state without waiting for the time to pass or force quitting the Application and restarting it.

The Excel-specific [`Application.Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.application.wait) also suffers from this issue, except that the app will not show as `not responding` in Task Manager in this case. It will still be just as unresponsive to the user.

A way to circumvent this problem is calling `DoEvents` in a loop, as other people have already pointed out. However, this comes with another issue. Because the application will try to execute VBA code as fast as possible, DoEvents is called at the maximum achievable rate essentially saturating the CPU completely on that single thread, leading to high, unnecessary CPU and power usage and potentially slowing down other more important tasks in the UI.

This is why the best way of getting VBA to pause execution is a combination of both methods, using `DoEvents` to stay responsive and `Sleep` to avoid maximum CPU usage. An implementation of this is presented in the following.

---

### Universal Solution

The following code implements a `WaitSeconds` `Sub` that will pause execution for a given amount of seconds while avoiding all of the above-mentioned issues.
It can be used like this:

```
Sub UsageExample()
    WaitSeconds 3.5
End Sub
```

This will pause the macro for 3.5 seconds, without freezing the application or causing excessive CPU usage. For this to work, just copy the following code to the top of any standard code module.

```
#If Mac Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub USleep Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "usleep" (ByVal dwMicroseconds As Long)
    #Else
        Private Declare Sub USleep Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "usleep" (ByVal dwMicroseconds As Long)
    #End If
#Else
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Sub MSleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #Else
        Private Declare Sub MSleep Lib "kernel32" Alias "Sleep" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #End If
#End If

'Sub providing a Sleep API consistent with Windows on Mac (argument in ms)
'Authors: Guido Witt-Dörring, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74262120/12287457
'         Cristian Buse,      https://stackoverflow.com/a/71176040/12287457
Public Sub Sleep(ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #If Mac Then 'To avoid overflow issues for inputs > &HFFFFFFFF / 1000:
        Do While dwMilliseconds And &H80000000
            USleep &HFFFFFED8
            If dwMilliseconds < (&H418937 Or &H80000000) Then
                dwMilliseconds = &H7FBE76C9 + (dwMilliseconds - &H80000000)
            Else: dwMilliseconds = dwMilliseconds - &H418937: End If
        Loop
        Do While dwMilliseconds > &H418937
            USleep &HFFFFFED8: dwMilliseconds = dwMilliseconds - &H418937
        Loop
        If dwMilliseconds > &H20C49B Then
            USleep (dwMilliseconds * 500& Or &H80000000) * 2&
        Else: USleep dwMilliseconds * 1000&: End If
    #Else
        MSleep dwMilliseconds
    #End If
End Sub

'Sub pausing code execution without freezing the app or causing high CPU usage
'Author: Guido Witt-Dörring, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457
Public Sub WaitSeconds(ByVal seconds As Single)
    Dim currTime As Single:  currTime = Timer()
    Dim endTime As Single:   endTime = currTime + seconds
    Dim cacheTime As Single: cacheTime = currTime
    Do While currTime < endTime
        Sleep 15: DoEvents: currTime = Timer() 'Timer function resets at 00:00!
        If currTime < cacheTime Then endTime = endTime - 86400! '<- sec per day
        cacheTime = currTime
    Loop
End Sub
```

<sub>[1] More information on the cross-platform `Sleep` included in the above code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71176040/12287457) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74262120/12287457).</sub>

If application freezing is not an issue, e.g. for very short delays or if user interaction is undesired, the best solution is to call `Sleep` directly. This is why, in the above solution, it is also declared as `Public`. Note that `Sleep` takes its argument as milliseconds.

```
'Does freeze application
Sub UsageExample()
    Sleep 3.5 * 1000
End Sub
```

**Important Notes:**

1. The time precision of the `Timer()` function used in this solution is better on Windows, however, the claim in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function), that resolution on Mac is one second, is wrong. Even on Mac, the resolution is better than 0.1 seconds. Still, you shouldn't expect a resolution much better than ~`0.1` seconds from this solution! `WaitSeconds 1` will wait around `1.015 ± 0.02` seconds on Windows.
2. If you plan on using this to pause your code for long periods of time, or even in a case like OP is dealing with, you are most likely not using the correct tool for the job. If you are using Excel, consider looking into [`Application.OnTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime). (See the following section)

---

### Alternatives to Pausing VBA Execution and Better Solution for OP

The question op has asked does not lead to the best solution for his problem. It's an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/905828).

It is not actually necessary to have VBA code running non-stop in the background in order to recalculate a Workbook every second. This is a typical example of a task that can also be achieved with [`Application.OnTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime).

A detailed guide including a copy-paste solution to recalculate any `Range` at any desired time interval `≥ 1s` is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73785869/12287457).

The big advantage of using `Application.OnTime` for this is that it avoids a continuously running macro and hence allows the use of other macros or other features that are unavailable while macros are running.

---

### Meta-Analysis of All Other Solutions in This Thread

The reason I even wrote this answer is that all other solutions presented in this thread (at the time this post was written) have **at least one of the following two severe drawbacks**:

1. They freeze the calling application completely, causing it to no longer respond to user input, or
2. They cause excessive CPU usage (100% on the calling application's thread) by calling `DoEvents` in a loop.

Additionally, many of the proposed solutions have other issues:

3. Some only work on Windows
4. Some only work in Excel
5. Some have an intrinsic imprecision of more than one second
6. Some have other problems or even bugs

The following table will give a short overview of all the solutions in this thread and their features

**Legend**

| Column | ✅ (Good) | ❌ (Bad) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| App Responds | App stays responsive and usable | Freezes calling app completely |
| CPU Usage | Practically no CPU usage | 100% CPU usage in the single executing thread |
| Cross-App | Works outside Excel | Works only in Excel |
| Win/Mac | Works on both, Windows and Mac | Only works on Windows |
| Precise | Time precision < 0.1 seconds | Time precision > 0.1 seconds (usually about 1 second) |
| Other Issues | No other issues | Has some other issues described in the table below |

**Overview**

| Solution By | App Responds | CPU Usage | Cross-App | Win/Mac | Precise | Other Issues |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Ben S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1544562/12287457) (accepted) | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| [Buggabill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1544582/12287457) | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| [Achaibou Karim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23984113/12287457) | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| [Maycow Moura](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56561558/12287457) | ✅ | ❌ | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| [clemo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19602211/12287457) | ✅ | ❌ | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| [cyberpunk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53392427/12287457) | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ |
| [dbuskirk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23550879/12287457) | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ |
| [Reverus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199690/12287457) | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ❌ |
| [Anastasiya-Romanova 秀](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38165352/12287457) | ❌ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| [Appscript.me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60579682/12287457) | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| [Brian Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32645114/12287457) | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ❌ |
| [g t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24726642/12287457) | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ❌ |
| [ITI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27532617/12287457) | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ❌ |
| [dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458837/12287457) | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ | ❌ | ❌ |
| [GWD (this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457) | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |

**Other issues**

| Solution by | Other issues |
| --- | --- |
| [cyberpunk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53392427/12287457) | This solution will sleep indefinitely if at the time of calling `Timer() + vSeconds > 172800` (`vSevonds` is the input value). In practice, this shouldn't be a big problem because `Timer()` is always ≤ 86400 so the input value needs to be bigger than 86400 which is one day. Such functions usually shouldn't be called for such long times anyways. |
| [Reverus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48199690/12287457) | This solution doesn't allow pausing for a specific amount of time at all! You just specify how often you want to call `DoEvents` before continuing. How long this is, depends on the speed of your system. On my PC, calling the function with the maximum value a `Long` can take (2147483647) (so the maximum time the function can pause) will pause for about 1434 seconds or about 24 minutes. Obviously, this is a terrible "solution". |
| [Brian Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32645114/12287457) | This solution will sleep indefinitely if at the time of calling `Timer() + sngSecs > 86400` (`sngSecs` is the input value). Because `Timer()` can return values up to 86400, calling this function right before midnight can cause this bug even with very small input values. This is a severe bug and should be considered! |
| [g t](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24726642/12287457) | This solution does not wait at all. If you consider its generalization, `Application.Wait Second(Now) + dblInput`, it will not wait at all for input values smaller than `CDbl(Now) - 60# / 86400#`, which is 44815 at the time of writing this, and for input values larger than that, it will wait for `dblInput - CDbl(Now) - Second(Now) / 86400#` days. While input values can be constructed that will make this wait for a reasonable amount of time, this is very difficult. A terrible "solution". |
| [ITI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27532617/12287457) | The comment describes this function as being able to cause delays of up to 99 seconds. This is wrong because input values where `T Mod 100 > 60`(`T` is the input parameter) will cause an error and hence stop execution indefinitely if the error is not handled by the calling code. You can confirm this by calling the function like this: `Delay 61` |
| [dave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458837/12287457) | This solution will work correctly but additionally sets `Application.EnableEvents = True` for no reason at all. If the calling code set this property to `False` and reasonably doesn't expect a function that has nothing to do with this to set it to `True`, this can lead to severe bugs in the calling code. If that line is deleted, the solution is fine. |

Comment: this looks extremely....thorough.  is this a copy/paste?

Comment: Hello @Keng. All of this is my original work. Where I had help (cross-platform `Sleep`, the source is clearly indicated. (I collaborated with @CristianBuse on that, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74262120/12287457) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71176040/12287457) as linked in the answer.) I enjoy writing detailed answers to old questions if I'm dissatisfied with the existing solutions. Another example see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457). It should be obvious that the meta-analysis can not be copy/paste because it's specific to this thread.

Answer (score 13):

The declaration for Sleep in kernel32.dll won't work in 64-bit Excel. This would be a little more general:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If
```

Comment: Fails to compile in Office 2013. The error checker in VBA for Office 2013 seems to ignore the compiler statements.

Comment: Compiles fine for me in Office 2013.

Comment: Most people agree that Win64/VBA7 dwMilliseconds is Long, not LongPtr. Excel VBA hides errors like this by doing stack correction after external calls, but errors like this will crash most versions of Open Office

Answer (score 8):

Just a cleaned up version of clemo's code - works in Access, which doesn't have the Application.Wait function.

```
Public Sub Pause(sngSecs As Single)
    Dim sngEnd As Single
    sngEnd = Timer + sngSecs
    While Timer < sngEnd
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub

Public Sub TestPause()
    Pause 1
    MsgBox "done"
End Sub
```

Comment: If `Timer` gives the number of seconds since midnight, then this approach fails if it is executed just before midnight (i.e., such that `sngEnd` is >= 86,400). At midnight, `Timer` resets to 0 and thus remains less than `sngEnd` forever.

Comment: P.S. The code from @clemo above does work any time of day.

Comment: @vknowles, what you said is absolutely true. And also can be compensated in below method. Since this method handles milliseconds, I think it's a safe bet.

```
Public Sub Sleep(sngSecs As Single)
    Dim sngEnd As Single
    sngEnd = Timer + (sngSecs / 1000)
    While Timer < sngEnd
        DoEvents
        **If (sngEnd - Timer) > 50000 Then
            sngEnd = sngEnd - 86400
        End If**
    Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

Most of the presented solutions use Application.Wait, which does not take in account the time (miliseconds) already elapsed since the currend second count started, so **they have an intrinsic imprecision of up to 1 second**.

**The Timer approach is the best solution**, but you have to take in account the reset at midnight, so here is a very precise Sleep method using Timer:

```
'You can use integer (1 for 1 second) or single (1.5 for 1 and a half second)
Public Sub Sleep(vSeconds As Variant)
    Dim t0 As Single, t1 As Single
    t0 = Timer
    Do
        t1 = Timer
        If t1 < t0 Then t1 = t1 + 86400 'Timer overflows at midnight
        DoEvents    'optional, to avoid excel freeze while sleeping
    Loop Until t1 - t0 >= vSeconds
End Sub
```

**USE THIS TO TEST ANY SLEEP FUNCTION:** (open debug Immediate window: CTRL+G)

```
Sub testSleep()
    t0 = Timer
    Debug.Print "Time before sleep:"; t0   'Timer format is in seconds since midnight

    Sleep (1.5)

    Debug.Print "Time after sleep:"; Timer
    Debug.Print "Slept for:"; Timer - t0; "seconds"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

Wait and Sleep functions lock Excel and you can't do anything else until the delay finishes. On the other hand Loop delays doesn't give you an exact time to wait.

So, I've made this workaround joining a little bit of both concepts. It loops until the time is the time you want.

```
Private Sub Waste10Sec()
   target = (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
   Do
       DoEvents 'keeps excel running other stuff
   Loop Until Now >= target
End Sub
```

You just need to call Waste10Sec where you need the delay

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative to sleep:

```
Sub TDelay(delay As Long)
Dim n As Long
For n = 1 To delay
DoEvents
Next n
End Sub
```

In the following code I make a "glow" effect blink on a spin button to direct users to it if they are "having trouble", using "sleep 1000" in the loop resulted in no visible blinking, but the loop is working great.

```
Sub SpinFocus()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 3   '3 blinks
Worksheets(2).Shapes("SpinGlow").ZOrder (msoBringToFront)
TDelay (10000)   'this makes the glow stay lit longer than not, looks nice.
Worksheets(2).Shapes("SpinGlow").ZOrder (msoSendBackward)
TDelay (100)
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

`Application.Wait  Second(Now) + 1`

Comment: WARNING: All solutions using 'Application.Wait' have 1 second imprecision. This method does not consider the milliseconds that already elapsed since the current second started... For example, if there is only 1 milisecond left until the time seconds change, you will only sleep for 1 milisecond. You are just comparing 2 rounded numbers instead of waiting for 1 second!

Answer (score 2):

```
Function Delay(ByVal T As Integer)
    'Function can be used to introduce a delay of up to 99 seconds
    'Call Function ex:  Delay 2 {introduces a 2 second delay before execution of code resumes}
        strT = Mid((100 + T), 2, 2)
            strSecsDelay = "00:00:" & strT
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(strSecsDelay))
End Function
```

Comment: WARNING: All solutions using 'Application.Wait' have 1 second imprecision. This method does not consider the milliseconds that already elapsed since the current second started... For example, if there is only 1 milisecond left until the time seconds change, you will only sleep for 1 milisecond. You are just comparing 2 rounded numbers instead of waiting for 1 second!

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the **Timer** function to pause the application. Insert this code to yours

```
T0 = Timer
Do
    Delay = Timer - T0
Loop Until Delay >= 1 'Change this value to pause time for a certain amount of seconds
```

Comment: If `Timer` gives the number of seconds since midnight, then this approach fails if it is executed just before midnight (i.e., such that `T0` is less than the number of delay seconds from midnight). At midnight, `Timer` resets to 0 before the delay limit is reached. `Delay` never reaches the delay limit, so the loop runs forever.

Comment: Since Timer produces non-integer values, you should use `Loop Until Delay >= 1`, or you risk going over 1 and never exiting the loop.

Answer (score 1):

i had this made to answer the problem:

```
Sub goTIMER(NumOfSeconds As Long) 'in (seconds) as:  call gotimer (1)  'seconds
  Application.Wait now + NumOfSeconds / 86400#
  'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))  'other
  Application.EnableEvents = True       'EVENTS
End Sub
```

Comment: WARNING: All solutions using 'Application.Wait' have 1 second imprecision. This method does not consider the milliseconds that already elapsed since the current second started... For example, if there is only 1 milisecond left until the time seconds change, you will only sleep for 1 milisecond. You are just comparing 2 rounded numbers instead of waiting for 1 second!

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
Application.wait now + timevalue("00:00:01")
or
Application.wait now + timeserial(0,0,1)

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
Threading.thread.sleep(1000)
```