# VB script + how to create delay in VB

Tags: vbscript

How to create a delay in VB script as the `sleep` command in linux?

Comment: look here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729075/how-to-set-delay-in-vbscript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `WScript.Sleep 2000`.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
WScript.Sleep 500 ' adjust the value
```