# How to pause a vbscript execution?

Tags: vbscript

How can I pause an execution of a script from within? Something like Sleep WinAPI function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set delay in vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729075/how-to-set-delay-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a `WScript` object and call the [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t81adfd.aspx) method on it:

```
Set WScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WScript.Sleep 2000 'Sleeps for 2 seconds
```

Another option is to import and use the WinAPI function [directly](http://stevehardie.com/index.php/2010/03/vbscript-sleep/) (only works in VBA, thanks [@Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen)):

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sleep 2000
```

Comment: Note: You can't run WinAPI functions from VBScript. Your second example works only in VB/VBA.

Comment: @Helen - thanks for the information. Didn't know about this limitation. Answer updated.

Comment: I just tried this and it seems that the `Set WScript = ...` statement is extraneous. Just the one line `WScript.Sleep 2000` worked for me (just like `WScript.Echo` always has).

Comment: @GordThompson - it depends on the script context you are in.

Comment: For me it worked without the line `Set WScript = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`, but if I included that line I got an error.

Answer (score 25):

Script snip below creates a pause sub that displayes the pause text in a string and waits for the Enter key.  z can be anything.  Great if multilple user intervention required pauses are needed.  I just keep it in my standard script template.

```
Pause("Press Enter to continue")

Sub Pause(strPause)
     WScript.Echo (strPause)
     z = WScript.StdIn.Read(1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 12):

With 'Enter' is better use ReadLine() or Read(2), because key 'Enter' generate 2 symbols. If user enter any text next Pause() also wil be skipped even with Read(2). So ReadLine() is better:

```
Sub Pause()
    WScript.Echo ("Press Enter to continue")
    z = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

More examples look in http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156589.aspx

Comment: I know. But accepted answer has trouble i pointed.
I want add a comment to accepted answer but i have not enough reputation. So I post another answer

Comment: @PlasmaPower This site is all about finding multiple answers to the same problem. When the question was asked back then not every possible programmer with every possible solution was present apparently. Good on Sergey for adding another answer. Sergey this was a good and acceptable answer, not a comment. +1