# How can I automatically log into a website using vbscript?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

Im trying to automatically log into a website using a script so our employees don't have to remember the admin password.

```
Dim IE 
Dim Helem
Set IE =CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")  
IE.Visible = 1  
IE.navigate "http://rentalapp.zillow.com/"  
Do While (IE.Busy)   
WScript.Sleep 10  
LoopSet 
Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("formUsername")  
Helem.Value ="username"  
Set Helem =IE.document.getElementByID("formPassword")  
Helem.Value = "password" 
Set Helem = IE.document.Forms(0)  
Helem.Submit
```

I've gotten this far from other posts I've seen but I keep getting an error saying:

```
Line: 10 
char: 2 Error: 
Object required 
code: 800A01A8 
source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

I've researched the code and and it says there is a typo somewhere but for the life of me I can't figure out where.

I'm not too familiar with vbscript but with functions like this I want to become more familiar with it. Please help.

Comment: Is `LoopSet` a typo? The `Set` keyword would belong in the next line.

Comment: No, Joe was right, formusername should be just username, I copied and pasted it from a prior script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("formUsername")  
Helem.Value ="username" <= this is line 10
```

Failed at line 10: looks like you failed to find an element with the ID "formUsername".

Take a look at the source of the page and check your ID is correct.

Comment: Thank you soooo much, ha it was just username. But hey how can I pause before another action I want to navigate to another page 2 seconds after the submit button fires off

Comment: @Jay_the_noob - "how can I pause..." - ask google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037180/how-to-pause-a-vbscript-execution

Answer (score 0):

```
Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("formUsername")  
==>
Set Helem = IE.document.getElementByID("formUsername")
```

as later in your code.