# WshShell.sleep not working on Windows 10

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, windows-10

I have a couple of questions about this. 1) Is there any reason WshShell.sleep Doesn't work on Windows 10? 2) What are the alternatives? They need to be compatible with Windows 7 too.

```
    set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    WshShell.sleep 10000
```

Creates the following error
http://prntscr.com/86o9ml
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[`Wscript.Shell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahcz2kh6(v=vs.84).aspx) does not contain a sleep method.  You want [`Wscript.Sleep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729075/how-to-set-delay-in-vbscript).

```
  Wscript.sleep 10000
```

The `Wscript` object will already exist, there is no need to create it.

Comment: Thanks! Do I need to `set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")` for the `WshShell.AppActivate` and `WshShell.SendKeys`?

Comment: Yes you do. Those are all methods on the Wscript.Shell object. All of it's methods are listed here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahcz2kh6(v=vs.84).aspx