# VBA Sleep Doesn't Work

Tags: vba, sleep

I know I'm doing something wrong here.  I'm trying to use the sleep function to delay my code, but I get "Sub or Function not defined" error.  Any tips?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

VBA does not have a `Sleep` function.

You can import it from Kernel32.dll like this:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

Note that this will freeze the application.
You can also call `DoEvents` in a `While` loop, which won't freeze the application.

Comment: Where in the code do I put that declaration?  I've tried sticking it in outside and inside of the sub I'm working on, but get errors both times.

Comment: Oh, oops, I was trying to put it into an excel object (silly me).  I put it in a module and now it works. Thanks so much! I checked your answer.

Comment: Despite the issue of hanging the application, I would prefer this method since the loop approach uses too much CPU.

Comment: @kalengi: You should be using async.

Comment: @SLaks async with Sleep, or how do you mean?

Comment: @kalengi: Ideally, `Await Task.Delay()`.  In VBA, I don't know whether there is any proper way to do it.

Comment: This solution does not work in 64-bit Windows applications or on Mac. `DoEvents` in a while loop will cause excessive CPU usage. Look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457), which solves all of these issues.

Answer (score 19):

Everything I've tried seems to hang the application, including Application.Wait.  This seems to work though:

```
waitTill = Now() + TimeValue("00:15:00")

While Now() < waitTill
    DoEvents
Wend
```

Comment: I like this one and it is working great.. only one exception. I can't find a way to do 500 ms ... So 1 second is the minimum wait time. Is there a way to do less than 1 second?

Comment: You can use GetSystemTime in kernel32.dll if you want higher resolution: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1618   Or if in Excel, you can call the spreadsheet now() function (as [now()] from VBA) which also has higher resolution: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.programming/-D6lkjJv2ew

Comment: In Excel you can use square brackets around the call to Now to get the Worksheet function version which has sub-second precision. `[Now()]`

Comment: One of the more elegant solutions :)

Comment: This is not a good solution, it causes high CPU usage (1 thread gets maximum usage) and doesn't provide sub 1-second resolution. Use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457), it solves both of these issues.

Answer (score 7):

You can also pause the current macro context with [`Application.Wait T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213656%28office.11%29.aspx) which won't block the whole process.

Comment: This only applies to `Excel.Application`.  The `Wait` method does not exist for other Office application object models.

Answer (score 4):

```
Application.Wait DateAdd("m", 10, Now) ' Wait for 10 Minutes
 Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now) ' wait for 10 seconds
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Looking at the link, it doesn't look like Babu's site, but rather like a useful read for the SO. Why would you want to delete it?

Comment: @PeterAlbert It is Babu's site. They have been spamming it a lot lately (multiple of their answers were deleted as spam because they didn't even contain this much info), and it's in their profile here.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - thanks for the info! I have to admit, I would not have noticed!

Comment: "m" = month; If you want minutes use "n"

Answer (score 2):

With this code Excel not freeze and the CPU usage is low:

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub Delay(s As Single)
    Dim TimeOut As Single
    TimeOut = Timer + s
    Do While Timer < TimeOut
        DoEvents
        Sleep 1 'With this line the CPU usage is 00 instead of 50 with an absolute error of +1ms and the latency of 1ms.
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: **This solution has a severe bug:** when `Timer + s > 86400`, which can easily happen if called shortly before midnight, it will never stop sleeping! Also, this solution doesn't work on Mac or in 64bit Windows applications. For a solution that deals with both of these issues, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457). Also, note that the time resolution of `Sleep` is [not actually 1 millisecond](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9518106/12287457).

Answer (score 2):

Pausing an application for 10 seconds:

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
```

Comment: Hi, is there any reason you can think of why this function would not be available in MS Outlook? For some reason, the Alt+F11 VBA editor does not seem to show it, and it won't work when I run it within functions on Outlook messages (from a Rule). Thanks!

Comment: @Kalin look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457) for a cross-platform, cross-app solution that doesn't freeze the application and doesn't cause excessive CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you need for cross compatability with 32-bit and 64-bit Windows machines.  The delay is in milliseconds, so use 1000 for a 1 second delay.

First, put this above your other Subs/Functions in a module.  On a 64-bit machine the line after "#Else" will be highlighted as if there is an error, but this isn't an issue.  The code will compile and run.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If
```

Now you can create a delay like this example with a 1.5 second delay:

```
Sub ExampleWithDelay()
    Msgbox "This is a message before the delay."
    Sleep 1500    ' delay of 1,000 milliseconds or 1.5 seconds
    Msgbox "This is a message -AFTER- the delay."
End Sub
```

As noted by @SLaks, this freezes the application (preventing user input) but you can also call `DoEvents` in a `While` loop.  See the example below.  It runs for 10 seconds and allows user interaction.

Every 1/10th of a second it updates the Excel status bar with:

1. The address of the active cell
2. A countdown

   ```
   Sub ExampleWithDelayInLoop()    ' for MS Excel

       Dim thisMessage As String
       Dim countdownText As String
       Dim i As Long

       Const TOTAL_SECONDS As Byte = 10

       For i = 1 To TOTAL_SECONDS * 10

           countdownText = Excel.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(TOTAL_SECONDS - (i / 10), 0)
           thisMessage = "You selected " & Excel.ActiveCell.Address & Space$(4) & countdownText & " seconds remaining"

           ' Show the address of the active cell and a countdown in the Excel status\
           '   bar.
           If Not Excel.Application.StatusBar = thisMessage Then
               Excel.Application.StatusBar = thisMessage
           End If

           ' Delay 1/10th of a second.
           '   Input is allowed in 1/10th second intervals.
           Sleep 100
           DoEvents

       Next i


       ' Reset the status bar.
       Excel.Application.StatusBar = False
   End Sub
   ```