# Internet Explorer - Fill Input Box with Text Mask Using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, vba, internet-explorer, excel

good afternoon!

I'm trying to run a Macro that opens a website, login, select an option in the menu, fill a text-box and click another button.

So far, I can open the website, login, select the option in the menu, but I can't get the text-box filled by any means. That text box has a text mask:

Format: 00000-000
Type: Numeric
Max Char.: 8
Min Char.: 8

```
Sub SAVE()


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Searching"


Sheets("WEB").Visible = True

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Dim dtInicio As Date
    Dim objIE As New DataObject



    Sheets("SAVE").Select
    Sheets("SAVE").Cells.Clear


S = 2
V = 2

SALVA = 0
Do While Sheets("Adress").Cells(V, 2) <> ""
    IE.Visible = True

    Sheets("WEB").Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "WEB"


'OPEN URL
    IE.navigate "URL HERE"

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Sleep (1000)
        DoEvents
    Wend



    IE.Document.forms(0).pUsrLg.Value = "user"
    IE.Document.forms(0).pUsrSn.Value = "password"
    IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "login();"

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Sleep (1000)
    DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "enviaPage('mod_pesquisa/DisponibilidadeNaoClientes.asp', 'GET', 'True', 'dv_pagina', 'pUsrId=0000050007', 'True', 389, 892);"

    While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Sleep (1000)
    DoEvents
    Wend
```

The Input I must fill looks like this:

```
<input name="pCepNr" id="pCepNr" type="text" class="st_cxt_01" style="height: 20px; width: 85px; background-color: #FFEEDD; color: #913A1A;">
```

Comment: How are you trying to fill in the text box? Does `IE.Document.getelementbyid("pCepNr").value = "BLAH"` simply not set the value or not show it?

Comment: Actually I've tried many ways to set it, none worked so far. I've tried as you mentioned, but it results in "Run Time Error 91".

Comment: What happens when you `Debug.Print` the value?  Does that return the same error?  Can you even `Set` an object to that element?

Comment: Yes, it return the same error, and I don't know if I can set an element to to that object, how do I check it? I'm sorry, I'm not a programmer hehe just trying to get it workin.. so I don't know much about VBA.. but what I find weird is that as you can see I can fill the other 2 input forms (pUsrLg and pUsrSn) fine, and they have the same class and all.. the only difference I can notice is the text mask.

Comment: Does the element exist before the last script you execute?

Comment: No, the last script loaded a new page where the element is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the method `IE.Document.getelementbyid("pCepNr").value` is returning error code 91
([Object not set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506(v=vs.60).aspx)), I suspect `.getElementById` is failing to find an HTML element with `id="pCepNr"`

Please confirm this by trying this in your code:

```
' snip ...
IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "enviaPage('mod_pesquisa/DisponibilidadeNaoClientes.asp', 'GET', 'True', 'dv_pagina', 'pUsrId=0000050007', 'True', 389, 892);"

While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Sleep (1000)
    DoEvents
Wend

Dim problemTextBox as Object
Set problemTextBox = IE.Document.getelementbyid("pCepNr")
```

I suspect it will throw the same error. (**EDIT** *See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737706/vba-sleep-doesnt-work/2737726#2737726) for the `Sleep` routine.*)

Unless you have the wrong id of the element you are looking for, the element simply doesn't exist when you try to access it.

If this script you are running ,

> ```
> IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "enviaPage('mod_pesquisa/DisponibilidadeNaoClientes.asp', 'GET', 'True', 'dv_pagina', 'pUsrId=0000050007', 'True', 389, 892);"
> ```

is what loads the element and the element doesn't exist before then, then your wait loop is failing to wait long enough for it to load.

I have noticed that for .asp pages `IE.Busy` or `IE.readyState` do not always work.  You can test that by either stepping through slowing with the debugger and accessing the input box after you know it is loaded or just by forcing a large (10 second) sleep.

If simply your wait loop is exiting before the element is loaded, then you will need a better waiting routine.  Here is one that I have used, parts of it are from other questions on SE.

```
Public Function ElementExists(document as Object, id As String) As Boolean

    Dim el As Object
    Set el = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next
    Set el = document.getElementById(id)

    On Error GoTo 0
    ElementExists = Not (el Is Nothing)

End Function
Public Function WaitForElement(document as Object, ByVal id As String, Optional ByVal timeout As Integer = 3) As Boolean

    Dim start_time As Single
    start_time = Timer

    Do While Not (ElementExists(document, id)) And start_time + timeout > Timer
        DoEvents
    Loop
    WaitForElement = ElementExists(document, id)

End Function
```

Calling `WaitForElement(IE.Document, "pCepNr")` will wait no more than 3 seconds for the element to load and will return whether the element is accessible (true|false).  3 seconds is optional you can increase or decrease as you see fit *eg* (`WaitForElement(IE.Document, "pCepNr", timeout:=10)`.

Comment: Oh man, you were spot on! It was the sleep time.. I forced a 10 seconds sleep time and it worked right way! Thank you so much for the help, you are the guy!