# Call Sleep("time") in VBA

Tags: vba, sleep, undefined-function

In VBA I use `Call Sleep(TIME)` where `TIME` is a value of some 10 msec. Worked fine wit Office 2003, now I have Office 2019, and the error message "Sub or Function not defined". Where do I find this function?

I defined

```vb
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

but it was rejected as error

Comment: Please refer to the [more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64289436/11683) on the suggested duplicate for x64 compatibility.