# Funny Behavior of Excel VBA Random number routine

Tags: vba, random, excel

I am trying to generate a bunch of random permutations via the the following algorithm through vba:

```
Function RandNumber(Bottom As Integer, Top As Integer, _
                Amount As Integer) As Integer()

Dim iArr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim temp As Integer
Dim bridge() As Integer

'Application.Volatile

ReDim iArr(Bottom To Top)

For i = Bottom To Top
    iArr(i) = i
Next i
Randomize
For i = Top To Bottom + 1 Step -1
    r = Int(Rnd() * (i - Bottom + 1)) + Bottom
    temp = iArr(r)
    iArr(r) = iArr(i)
    iArr(i) = temp
Next i

ReDim Preserve bridge(1 To Amount)
For i = Bottom To Bottom + Amount - 1
    bridge(i - Bottom + 1) = iArr(i)
Next i

RandNumber = bridge

End Function
```

What `RandNumber` essentially does is that it randomly gives a permutation based on the bottom and top values provided by the user. Example `RandNumber(1,2,1)` will either be `1` or `2` randomly.

Now I am testing this function through the following routine

```
Sub RandNos()
Dim z() As Variant
ReDim Preserve z(1 To 2560)
For i = 1 To 2560
z(i) = RandNumber(1, 2, 1)
Next i
For i = 1 To 2560
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0) = z(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

To my utter amazement the 'random' numbers are repeating exactly after 256 runs! (Ok, the value 2560 for `i` above is not exactly a co-incidence. I was suspecting that there is some pattern going on around 256 rows and thus took `i` as 2560)

Moreover, when I test the above function with slightly modified subroutine:

```
Sub RandNos2()
For i = 1 To 2560
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Offset((i - 1) Mod 256 + 1, Int((i - 1) / 256)) = RandNumber(1, 2, 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

the pattern is gone. (At least the pattern of repeating after 256 values is gone. Not sure if another pattern emerges).

Now based on my knowledge the `Randomize` is supposed to control the randomness by generating appropriate seeds and `Randomize` in vba takes the seed from the `timer`. So my hypothesis is that in the 1st `RandNos()` subroutine the updates happen so quickly that the seeds don't get updated fast enough. The fact that pattern is gone when I test with the second subroutine, since in the second routine excel takes longer to write the code in the worksheet and hence the gives the code some chance to update the `timer` and with it the seed of the Random numbers - supports my hypothesis.

So my question here is

1. Is my hypothesis correct.
2. Should I still hope to generate a 'random' pattern in Excel VBA.
3. Am I making a wrong use of `Randomize` here

Thanks in advance for your suggestions on the issue.

EDIT: One of the suggestions in the comment was that we should call `Randomize` only once. I tried doing that and it seems to work. However, I would still like to know what goes wrong using `Randomize` as above.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you should call Randomize once only.

Comment: I am running a subroutine which repeatedly calls this function, then `Randomize` should be in `sub` rather than `function`?

Comment: Yes. Or if RandNos() is called more than once, use Randomize in the method that calls RandNos().

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I encourage you to post this as an answer.

Comment: @DougGlancy Encouragement yielded to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in answer to your edit, your hypothesis is correct.

Randomize takes the time and generates a seed. A seed is just a starting point for Rnd.

However, note that Randomize is not one-to-one which means that for any given input into Randomize (i.e. the time) it doesn't generate the same seed every time.  You appear to have discovered that Randomize has a sequence of 256 seeds for every given input.  Therefore, you get a repeating sequence of 256 numbers which were supposed to be random but which clearly are not.

Reference: The VBA help page for Randomize and CS classes

Answer (score 3):

You should call `Randomize` once only. If `RandNos()` is called more than once, use `Randomize` in the method that calls `RandNos()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but why is the pattern not visible in the routine `RandNos2` above and why repeat after 256?

Answer (score 0):

just for future reference to anyone else who encounters this problem, I decided to just try "slowing down" the subroutine enough to allow the system timer to reset. `Application.wait` did not work well, but I found that by including a simple `debug.print` line above the `randomize` call, it slowed the execution down just enough to get it to not repeat every 256. This not dramatically increase the overall run time of the subroutine. Just a thought for folks who would not mind sacrificing a little bit of optimization for a very simple fix on the pseudo-randomness.

Comment: Just Fyi, I don't know what time you used, but, `Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))` doesn't work well because it actually waits from (very nearly) zero TO 1 second. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544526/how-to-pause-for-specific-amount-of-time-excel-vba