# Sqr function stopping vba code (?!)

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, sqr

Sorry for my stupid question, but I can´t understand just for it be so simple.

Excel 2010 stops running when I try the code below:

```
Sub Delay()

Dim j As Double
Dim i As Double
Dim k As Double

    For i = 1 To 1000000
        j = Sqr(i)
        k = 0
        Do While k < 1000000
            j = Sqr(k)
            k = k + 1
        Loop
    Next

End Sub
```

This sub does nothing, just spends time. So why excel is not responding?

VBA can´t be so weak. What am I losing?

Thanks.

Comment: You are asking it to calculate over a trillion square roots, even if it could do a billion per second it would take nearly 20 minutes

Comment: Thanks, Joe, I didn´t stop to calculate the time it could take. I tried for i <= 10,000 and k <= 10,000, what means one hundred milion of iteractions, and it spent nearly 4 seconds, but didn´t stop. I toke this sugestion (but with only one loop) from a microsoft page.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing there is causing excel to go into a loop for 1,000,000 iterations. What you're trying to do is probably best answered by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544526/how-to-pause-for-specific-amount-of-time)