# Waiting in Excel Macros

Tags: excel, vba, wait, excel-2011

I am recording an Excel Macro where I would like it to wait half a second before switching to the next value. I am plotting changes to a graph, and right now it just storms through the values so you dont really see any changes. I would therefor like it to wait half a second before moving on.

The Macro Im using looks like this:

```
Sub Macro2()
' Macro2 Macro
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
    Range("C2").Select
End Sub
```

Now I would love to do something like the following but it doesnt work.

```
Sub Macro2()
' Macro2 Macro
    Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Range("C1").Select
Sleep (100)
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
Range("C2").Select
Sleep (100)
End Sub
```

Help please? I'm on a Mac Office Excel 2011.

Comment: You can also wait only milliseconds, see my answer below

Comment: What's 'Sleep' on a Mac? I'm familiar with importing the `Sleep()` API call from Kernel32 in Windows, but I doubt that the code would work on planet Apple... So that's one of your problems, right there.  The answers involving `Application.Wait()` will show you the way forward, as that's native to Office on all platforms.

Comment: FYI, Wait use simplified: 1second will wait from (very nearly) zero, TO 1s. 2 will wait from 1 TO 2 seconds ETC. I.e. 1 second imprecision due to ignoring the milliseconds elapsed so far in the second. Details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544526/how-to-pause-for-specific-amount-of-time-excel-vba

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `Application.Wait(time)`. It pauses the macro until the specified time, then returns `True`.

To wait 1 second:

```
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
```

(Tested in Excel 2010 on Windows)

Comment: Thank you - works perfectly! I knew it was one of those easy things where I guess i was more inhibited by not really know how to ask the question than understanding the answer (if that makes sense) ...

Answer (score 3):

`Application.Wait(Now + s / 86400)` is one way, where `s` is the number of seconds. There are 86400 seconds in a day. Note that the wait time could be greater than this due to how this works internally.

If this isn't reliable enough (it seems that `s` needs to be a whole number), and your OS supports it, then you could always resort to using the kernel function which will give you sub-second granularity:

`Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)`

Include this at the top of your module, and call in the normal way: `Sleep(500)` will pause for (at least) 1/2 a second.

Comment: This does not seem to be working. When I try to count time with the following function, I always get 0. I feel no delay too. `Dim c: c = Timer: Application.Wait (Now + 0.5 / 86400): MsgBox Timer - c`

Comment: Perhaps the VBA interpreter is doing some funky rounddown. Did you try 1.0 / 86400?

Comment: Yes, it works then, although `1.0` gets converted to `1#`.

Comment: That's fine. It needs to be a floating point literal else the division will round. It might be better though to call the kernel function as above.

Comment: Loving this kernel function! But the first option... repeating myself, gives me 0 delay

Comment: Hum. I suspect VBA is doing something funky behind the scenes. Seems that 1 second is the finest amount of granularity you can use. I've amended the answer.

Comment: This question was asked by someone working in the Office for Macintosh environment: are you sure that you can declare `Sleep()` ?

Comment: @Bathsheba is correct: the granularity of `Application.Wait` is 1 second: and the precision (or lack of it) is driven by task swapping and thread priority. Nevertheless, Wait is still a good tool: VBA is suspended but background calculation and incoming data feeds are still processed, unlike Sleep, which suspends the entire application... Which is often exactly what you wanted to do.

Comment: @nile that's a good point. I can't verify so I've fudged the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just on a side note - when using the macro recorder, go through the code generated afterwards and see if you can remove the `select` statements.

Your code would then become

```
Sub Macro2()
' Macro2 Macro
    Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    ' Whichever method you want to use from the other two answers put here
    Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
End Sub
```

This will make it a lot more efficient. I haven't added the answer to your question as it's already been answered

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
```

This should wait for maximum 1 second. But you will never be sure with VBA. This waits for the specified time, so if you had `11:30:30` *and a half*, you will wait until `11:30:31`, which will make it only for 0,5 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

As simple as that `Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)` for a 1/10sec :

```
Sub Macro2()
' Macro2 Macro
Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")) '1sec
Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "2"
Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001) '1/10sec
Range("C2").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tested that?

Comment: @Nile : Yes, I tested it on Excel 2013 64bits and Win7 64bits, no problem with it!

Comment: @R3iK ...And did it wait for a tenth of a second, or for an integer (or zero) number of seconds? Have a look at testing that with a precision timer API function, or the `VBA.DateTime.Timer` property, which returns a single-precision float, accurate to ±0.01 seconds, instead of the ±1 second precision functions passing the VBA 'Time Serial' variant.

Comment: @Nile : I just retried and most of the time, I've a got a decimal and sometimes got 0... A bit astonished by the 0...