# Pressing button every 30 sec vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a form button and a macro is assigned to it. I want that form button to be pressed every 30 seconds. Is that possible via vba code, ?

Comment: Look at Application.OnTime

Comment: If the Button Click Calls any Subroutine, i would suggest calling the Subroutine for every 30 secs.Further to delay have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544526/how-to-pause-for-specific-amount-of-time

Comment: Yes its possible `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "your subroutine"`

Answer (score 2):

This is a X-Y problem. Your button calls a routine (macro), so call that macro directly instead of having to press the button every 30 seconds.

You can use `Application.OnTime` for this.
Example code:

```
Sub myMacro()

Dim a as Integer

a = dostuff()
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "myMacro"   'This will cause the sub "myMacro" to execute every 30 seconds, starting when you first call it anywhere

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

```
Sub mycode()
    MsgBox ("Hello Shajee Rehman")
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:30"), "mycode"
End Sub
```