# Wscript.sleep 1000 not working

Tags: vba, excel, wsh

I have the following VBA code:

```
Set wshshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshshell.SendKeys "{F3}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
```

I get the following error on the `WSCript.Sleep` line:

> Run time error 424: Object required

Comment: Could you provide details about your system. The information provided is inadequate for proper analysis. Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask at this link

Comment: That code works for me - no errors generated - and, if I switch the last two statements around, there is a 1 second delay before the `F3` is performed.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in VBA or in WScript?

Comment: i am trying to do it in vba

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pause for specific amount of time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1544526/692942).

Comment: This whole thread, question and answers are duplicates. Learn to use search, better yet try this [`site:stackoverflow.com ` prefix on searches in Google](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=SAV6WMvVOu3v8AeX-5mAAg&gws_rd=cr&fg=1#q=site:stackoverflow.com+).

Comment: @Lankymart I agree that the answers supplied in that duplicate could be used as a workaround - but not one of them explain why `WScript.Sleep 1000` doesn't work, which is what this question is about.

Comment: @YowE3K That's because there not trying to shoehorn a scripting technology into VBA, but take your point. In VBA *(as long as the host supports `Application`)* then `Application.Wait` is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

`WScript.Sleep` only runs when used inside scripting host controls. VBA doesn't support it. You can, however use the following example to delay.

```
  #If VBA7 Then
        Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #Else
        Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    #End If
    Sub Test()

        MsgBox "one"
        Sleep 1000
        MsgBox "Two"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Related - [A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544526/how-to-pause-for-specific-amount-of-time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23550879/692942)