# Sendkey twice based on success?

Tags: vba, excel, sendkeys

I was using `sendkey` to access Power Query and connect to SharePoint Folder. Everything was smooth until the Power Query Data Preview Dialog appears.

How do I allow `sendkey` to continue after the dialog appears? I'm using button to start macro and using Excel 2016.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim spPath As String
    Dim strkeys As String

    spPath = "" 'SharePoint Link

    strkeys = "%APNFO" & spPath & "{Enter}{TAB 4}{Enter}" 
    'stops at first{Enter}, {TAB 4}{Enter} for EDIT
    Call SendKeys(strkeys)

End Sub
```

**Update**

Also tried to `sendkey` twice with `True` but same result, Stops at dialog.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim spPath As String
    Dim strkeys As String
    Dim strkeys2 As String

    spPath = ""

    strkeys = "%APNFO" & spPath & "{Enter}"
    strkeys2 = "{TAB 4}{Enter}"
    Call SendKeys(Trim(strkeys), True)
    Call SendKeys(Trim(strkeys2), True)
    Debug.Print strkeys2

End Sub
```

**Update2**

I tried what @peh suggested, using `sleep()` and `Application.wait()`. I found out that once the macro is initialized, `sendkey1` started and stopped by the `Application.wait()`. Only after the waiting time ends, then `sendkey1` is being processed. And once `sendkey1` started, `sendkey2` also starts.

Also tried adding `DoEvents`, `sendkey1` works perfect. However only after clicking the **Cancel** button, `Application.wait()` and `sendkey2` will start.

```
Call SendKeys(Trim(strkeys))
Debug.Print Now & "Send Key 1"
'Do Events
Application.wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
Call SendKeys(Trim(strkeys2), True)
Debug.Print Now & "Send Key 2"
```

**Pannel**

[image]

Comment: what you need is a command to wait some seconds between the 2 sendkeys to give the dialog time to load. See: [How to pause for specific amount of time? (Excel/VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544526/how-to-pause-for-specific-amount-of-time-excel-vba). But you can't guarantee that the dialog is really loaded after that amount of time, just estimate.

Comment: If you want to be sure the dialogue box has loaded instead of just using a timer, check my answer below.

Comment: Will test out. The dialog only contains the SharePoint link with data preview. Not sure whether it takes the link as captions.

Comment: Have you considered using the Microsoft UI Automation framework? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview. I've used this in VBA before for some stubborn buttons etc. There is a DLL that you can access with VBA. This could be a more reliable method to do what you are after.

Answer (score 6):

If the dialogue box is the same every time, or contains a consistent string of text in the caption, you may be able to use it's caption to detect when it appears using this function in a loop with a timer that searches for a reasonable amount of time for the dialogue box:

```
Private Function GetHandleFromPartialCaption(ByRef lWnd As Long, ByVal sCaption As String) As Boolean

Dim lhWndP As Long
Dim sStr As String
GetHandleFromPartialCaption = False
lhWndP = FindWindow(vbNullString, vbNullString) 'PARENT WINDOW
Do While lhWndP <> 0
    sStr = String(GetWindowTextLength(lhWndP) + 1, Chr$(0))
    GetWindowText lhWndP, sStr, Len(sStr)
    sStr = Left$(sStr, Len(sStr) - 1)
    If InStr(1, sStr, sCaption) > 0 Then
        GetHandleFromPartialCaption = True
        lWnd = lhWndP
        Exit Do
    End If
    lhWndP = GetWindow(lhWndP, GW_HWNDNEXT)
Loop
End Function
```

Where sCaption is the name of your dialogue box. Then in your main body of code use:

```
If GetHandleFromPartialCaption(lhWndP, "Your Dialogue Box Caption") = True Then
SendKeys(....
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: I have been working with a similar issue :) If you found my answer helpful, please mark it as an answer or upvote @ppz - Thanks and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Hi, sorry just managed to test out your answer. It does not seem to work,the function and `FindWindow` is highlighted, i think something went wrong while searching the windows. I'm following your guide `If GetHandleFromPartialCaption(lhWndP, spPath) = True Then
    Call SendKeys(Trim(strkeys2), True)
    Debug.Print spPath
    End If`

Comment: If that screenshot above is your pop up then this will not work as far as I'm aware. That window does not have a caption for my function to search for, sorry about that. The image wasn't available when i posted this answer, I was assuming it was a standard windows pop up window with a caption.

Comment: @Petrichor Anyways for the function, it's still very useful. I'm aware of that and updated that's why I updated the Image for reference. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am on my linux box right now so I can't tinker with this to test, but you might attempt to read other properties of the window with a utility like:

https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=28220

> Edit: if `SendKeys` absolutely won't work, and you don't want to go the UI automation route, *and* you don't mind a dependency, you could install AutoHotkey and script that from VBA (e.g. using the `Shell()` command). AHK is more robust when it comes to keyboard macro automation.

If you had a unique classname, for example, you could use `FindWindowEx` to get the window handle:

Module-scoped ~

```
#If VBA7 Then
'32-bit declare
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "USER32" _
                              Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, _
                              ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
#Else
'64-bit declare
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "USER32" _
                              Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, _
                              ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
#End If
```

Procedure ~

```
Dim appcaption as String
appcaption = "Excel"

#If VBA7 Then
Dim parenthandle as Long, childhandle as Long
#Else
Dim parenthandle as LongPtr, childhandle as LongPtr
#End If
parenthandle = FindWindow(vbNullString, appcaption)

If parenthandle Then

    childhandle = GetWindow(parenthandle, GW_CHILD)1   
    Do Until Not childhandle
        childhandle = GetWindow(childhandle, GW_HWNDNEXT)
    Loop

End If

If childhandle Then
    '
End If
```

This code is only proof of concept, as you could have muliple Excel Windows open, for example. It should give a good starting point, however.