# How to loop through the same cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("C10").Select

    For Range("C10").Value = 0 To 35
        Range("C10").Value = Range("C10").Value + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

I have written the above code for a cell to loop through the values = 0 to 35 . I am doing this because there are other formulas whose values change according to the value of Range("C10").

The code does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an increment variable to your For ... Next loop.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 35
        Range("C10").Value = i

        'do other stuff here
    
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a good way to do what you want:

You'd better use a counter variable, and do something like this:

```
for counter = 0 to 35:
  Range("C10").Value = counter
  // check the values of the things you want to verify,
  // e.g. by putting them in some cells for verification afterwards,
  // like "Range("D10").Offset(0,counter) = ...
Next
```

(This is just pseudo-code, there might be some syntax errors)

Answer (score 0):

This one would loop from 0 to 35, changing the value of `Range("A1")` with `i` on every second. Looks animated:

```
Public Sub LoopMe()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 35
        Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = i
        Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Next

End Sub
```

- [How to pause for specific amount of time? (Excel/VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544526/how-to-pause-for-specific-amount-of-time-excel-vba)