# VBA Excel: Macro should start after timer expires

Tags: excel, vba, timer

I am working with Visual Basic Application on Excel. I have a Macro, which should be executed after a time delay. I want to track the waiting time with a timer meanwhile.
I have created an additional module in which I have the following functions:

```
Public Sub start_time()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "next_moment"
End Sub

Public Sub end_time()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "next_moment", , False
End Sub

Public Sub next_moment()
If Worksheets("Messwerte").Range("A1").Value = 0 Then Exit Sub
Worksheets("Messwerte").Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Messwerte").Range("A1").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")
start_time
End Sub
```

I have my timer in the cell Worksheets("Messwerte").Range("A1").Value.
The structure of my code is now the following:

For Loop
Code Block 1
Call start_time #Waiting should be applied here
Code Block 2
End For Loop

My problem is now that the timer starts at start_time, but Code Block 2 is also starting. I want to have my timer and when my timer shows "00:00:00" then Code Block 2 should start.

On the forums I just found solutions to either having a timer or to wait until the code is continued but not both working like I want to.
Does someone has a solution on this?

Thanks

Comment: One advantage of `OnTime` is that it's "non-blocking" (other things can happen while you're waiting for it to fire)  Unfortunately this means your code does not wait for the process to complete - it calls `start_time` and then immediately continues.

Comment: To fix this you need to cache the state of the loop (eg. store the counter in a global or Static variable) and have a callable entry point which can be called to continue the loop when the timer expires.  Difficult to make concrete suggestions without seeing the actual loop code.

Comment: I've never used OnTime before, so be aware it _may_ have the same quirk as Application.Wait, in that: a 1 second wait, depending on the millisecond it was triggered, will wait from (very near) 0, _up to_ 1 sec. For detail See [How to pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544526/how-to-pause-for-specific-amount-of-time-excel-vba). For more granular control see "Sleep" in that link. Also, I think Wait and Sleep both _do_ "block".

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which is not clean, but it does work. Hopefully it helps you. 
I created a function, which is a boolean and becomes false, when the timer is on 0.

```
Public Function Check_Time() As Boolean
    If Sheets("Timer_Tabular").Range("Timer_Position").Value = 0 Then
        Check_Time = False
    Else
        Check_Time = True
    End If
End Function
```

The code has the following structure:

```
#Code before the waiting
Dim Waiting as Boolean
Waiting = True

'Wait until timer is zero
 Do While Waiting
    If Check_Time() = True Then
    'Enables working on excel while doing nothing.
       DoEvents
    ElseIf Check_Time() = False Then
       Waiting = False
       Exit Do
    End If
 Loop
#Code Block, which is executed after waiting time.
```

So the Macro is catched at this point inside the while loop and the while loop breaks, when the timer is 0. The DoEvents "unfreezes" the excel screen. 
Endresult is: The macro code stops running, but the timer goes on. If the timer is 0 the code will be continued.