# How to create an auto-scroll in Excel VBA that pauses when any key is pressed?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large amount of data to scroll through every day and an autoscroll macro that pauses when a key is pressed (and resumes with a button push) would be a big help.

So far, I've tried:

```
Sub Autoscroll()

Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

RowCount = Range("Table").Rows.Count

For i = RowCount + 1 To 2 Step -1
    Range("A" & i).Select
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Next i


End Sub
```

But this doesn't achieve what I want for a few reasons:

1. It doesn't pause when I press a key
2. It can't go faster than 1 second. (I could use the Sleep function to make the scroll move faster)

Looking for some recommendations about the best way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: This screams of an XY problem. That being said, does your mouse have an m-3 because it does basically this.

Comment: @Warcupine, I'm trying to solve this through a macro. Again, it's a large amount of data and wreaks havoc on my carpal tunnel to scroll with the keyboard or mouse.

Comment: Push the middle mouse button on your mouse and move your mouse slightly downward... does that work?

Comment: Not a bad suggestion @GWD but I am trying to accomplish this with a macro so I can regulate speed precisely. Thank you

Comment: @Zauberflöte, have you tried the answer I posted?

Comment: I will try shortly and let you know -- thank you very much

Comment: Thank you so much, @GWD, this is what I was hoping for.  I tweaked it a bit so that it would start from the current row (for pausing and unpausing), but this is it.  That's a complicated series of Do loops, a bit too advanced for me at the moment. Thank you for the help. I will learn from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using a macro try this, it should do the trick (if you are using Windows!).

You have to press the return key to interrupt. If you'd prefer a different key let me know.

```vb
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
#End If

'Sub pausing code execution without freezing the app or causing high CPU usage
'Author: Guido Witt-Dörring, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457
Public Sub WaitSeconds(ByVal seconds As Single)
    Const VK_RETURN = &HD
    Dim currTime As Single, endTime As Single, cacheTime As Single
    currTime = Timer(): endTime = currTime + seconds: cacheTime = currTime
    Do While currTime < endTime
        If GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN) Then
            Sleep 200
            Do Until GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)
                DoEvents: Sleep 15
            Loop
            Sleep 200
        End If
        DoEvents: Sleep 15: currTime = Timer()
        'The following is necessary because the Timer() function resets at 00:00
        If currTime < cacheTime Then endTime = endTime - 86400! 'seconds per day
        cacheTime = currTime
    Loop
End Sub

Sub Autoscroll()
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    RowCount = Range("Table").Rows.Count
    For i = RowCount + 1 To 2 Step -1
        WaitSeconds 0.5 '<-- this is how long it waits at every row,
        Range("A" & i).Select 'set it to your desired value
    Next i
End Sub
```