# Workaround for Application.OnKey in VBA under Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I have a Excel-VBA-Macro checking technical parameters in a while-loop that ends at a fixed point in time. To stop the macro  before this point in time with a keyboard-input, I tried the Application.OnKey command in vba. The problem structure is illustrated by the following code example:

```
Sub EndlessLoop()
    Application.OnKey "{ESC}", "QuitLoop"
    Do While True
        ' Code for the check of technical parameters
    Loop
End Sub

Sub QuitLoop()
    ' Code for final operations before quit
End Sub
```

Execution of EndlessLoop keeps running endless after pressing  ESC-key. Microsoft says, that OnKey ist actually not working (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey):
There is no way to currently detect the Command key in recent versions of Office VBA. Microsoft is aware of this and is looking into it.

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

As described, I tried some code examples with the result described above.

Task manager is no solution, because it just kills the appliction without executing the final operations before quit.

`Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer` does not work as well and ends with an error message.

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState causes an error message? - Are we talking about `Err.LastDLLError` - because if VBA itself throws the error message, the problem is not with the DLL but with your implementation. - If your code does not produce inputs, you could maybe use `GetLastInputInfo` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getlastinputinfo)

Comment: The "not working" you mentioned and linked is talking about the command key: "Command * (asterisk) Only applies to Mac; may only work on Excel 2011 for Mac and not later versions." - so everything should work fine. I'm assuming the problem lies with your implementation - To start with: you are never actually Exiting your infinite loop. It just keeps running forever. How is it supposed to be stopped? - You should also be aware, that VBA is single threaded - meaning a your infinite loop blocks any other code from being executed (until it's done, which it is never)

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74524618/12287457) for an example of how `GetAsyncKeyState` can be used to exit an infinite loop.