# Can not get bubble sort to run in excel's developer mode

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run what is supposed to be a simple bubblesort algo in excel.
Every time I've tried to run bubble sort, I get an error stating, "Compile error
sub or function is not defined." I am using the code my professor gave me.
Please help.

```
Sub BubbleSort()

'   Sorts an array using bubble sort algorithm

For i = 1 To 20
    For j = 1 To 20 - i
            If Cells(j, 1) > Cells(j + 1, 1) Then
            Temp = Cells(j, 1)
            Sleep 10
            Cells(j, 1) = Cells(j + 1, 1)
            Cells(j + 1, 1) = Temp
            
            
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:001"))
            
            
        End If
    
    Next
Next




End Sub
```

I have tried using a vb sytax checker. But quite frankly, I have no experience with vb and do
not know where to start.

Comment: You might be interested in the following link  https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?473677-VB6-Sorting-algorithms-%28sort-array-sorting-arrays%29

Comment: Your problem seems to be that the `Sub` `Sleep` is not defined. Try removing the line `Sleep 10` from your code as even if you declare `Sleep` it will only wait about 15 milliseconds so it won't make any conceivable difference. Also, you use `TimeValue("0:00:001")` but `Application.Wait` can only wait full seconds, e.g. `TimeValue("00:00:01")`. If you want to wait a fraction of a second every iteration I suggest you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74387976/12287457) about how to pause vba code execution.

Answer (score 0):

### Bubble Sort a Single-Column Range

[image]

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

' Sorts the range A1:A20 using the bubble sort algorithm
Sub BubbleSort()

    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 1
    Const LAST_ROW As Long = 20

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve
 
    Dim Temp, i As Long, j As Long

    For i = FIRST_ROW To LAST_ROW - 1
        For j = i + 1 To LAST_ROW
            If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value > ws.Cells(j, "A").Value Then
                Temp = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
                ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = ws.Cells(j, "A").Value
                ws.Cells(j, "A").Value = Temp
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    MsgBox "Column range sorted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used this code and it worked. My class is supposed to focus on python 3 but I guess I have to take a vb course on udemy to supplement my university classes. Thank you again

Comment: You need to be careful because this is just an illustrative code. You would never ever do this in this way. First of all, Excel has a `Sort` method and in Microsoft 365 it got the `SORT` and `SORTBY` functions all of them using the by far superior so-called stable sort which is also many times faster. Secondly, if you would want to bubble-sort the values from a range, you would first write the values to an array and sort the data in the array and then write the sorted data back to the range. Note that there are faster algorithms like the quick-sort or the merge-sort algorithms.

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008. I'll keep this in mind and will heed your warning. I am genuinely grateful for your help and the help others provided.

Answer (score 0):

Sleep is a windows function and not a VBA Function, but you can still use this function in VBA code by calling the windows Sleep API after declaring it

eg:

```
#If VBA7 Then
 Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems
#Else
 Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds as Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems
#End If
```

Better alternative is to use `Application.Wait`

Here is the working code to wait for 10 seconds

```
Sub BubbleSort() '   Sorts an array using bubble sort algorithm

For i = 1 To 20
    For j = 1 To 20 - i
            If Cells(j, 1) > Cells(j + 1, 1) Then
            Temp = Cells(j, 1)
            Application.Wait ("00:00:10")

            Cells(j, 1) = Cells(j + 1, 1)
            Cells(j + 1, 1) = Temp
            
            
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:001"))
            
            
        End If
    
    Next
```

Next
End Sub

Comment: I want to thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. Unfortunately, I just can not get it to work. I tried the corrected code above but it just hangs.

Comment: I looked at my excel sheet again and noticed there was an extra cell that did not need to be there. I removed it and it worked. Thank you so much!