# How would I take information from fields in a .pdf form and use to fill a new blank row in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am putting together a database on Excel that sstores contact information for a group of people. This information is gathered through a .pdf that people fill out on their computer and e-mail into me.

Sometimes, I have to share the information about a specific person by making up a summary of somebody's information. To do so, I have the following Macro that opens a .pdf tempalte and fills in the details.

My questions is, is there a simple way to have this Macro do the opposite? That is, take fields from a .pdf and use the information to populate a new row in my Excel table.

```
Sub CreatePDFForms():

Dim PDFTemplateFile, NewPDFName, SavePDFFolder, FullName As String
Dim ApptDate As Date
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long
With Sheet1

If .Range("E2").Value = Empty Or .Range("E4").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Both PDF Template and Saved PDF Locations are required for macro to run"
    Exit Sub
End If

LastRow = .Range("B9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Last Row
PDFTemplateFile = .Range("E2").Value 'Template File Name
SavePDFFolder = .Range("E4").Value 'Save PDF Folder
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PDFTemplateFile
Application.Wait Now + 0.00006

CustRow = .Range("K2")
FullName = .Range("B" & CustRow).Value 'Full Name
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys FullName, True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001

Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
Application.SendKeys .Range("H" & CustRow).Value, True 'Date of Birth
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys Format(.Range("I" & CustRow).Value, "####-###-####"), True 'Phone
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("L" & CustRow).Value, True 'School
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("N" & CustRow).Value, True 'House
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("O" & CustRow).Value, True 'Housemaster
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys Format(.Range("P" & CustRow).Value, "####-###-####"), True 'Housemaster Phone
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("AC" & CustRow).Value, True 'Emergency Contact
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys Format(.Range("AF" & CustRow).Value, "###-###-####"), True 'Emergency Phone
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True

Application.SendKeys .Range("AE" & CustRow).Value, True 'Emergency EMAIL
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True


Application.SendKeys "^(p)", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00003
Application.SendKeys "{Enter}", True
Application.Wait Now + 0.00007

Application.SendKeys "^(q)", True
Application.SendKeys "{numlock}%s", True


End With
End Sub
```

EDIT: The comments have directed me to other questions like mine, but these do not provide a means within VBA to do this, they require using other 3rd parties software. Here is some code I have developed from other users' to do the reverse, the problem I am having now is that Excel refuses to paste. This is a problem I have seen mentioned here ([How to copy-paste from DOS application to Excel using SendKeys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282825/how-to-copy-paste-from-dos-application-to-excel-using-sendkeys)) but is unresolved.

```
Sub GetPDFForms()
Dim PDFFile As String, textPDF As String
Dim ApptDate As Date
Dim objPDF As MSForms.DataObject
Dim CustRow, LastRow As Long

With Sheet1
If .Range("O2").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Must browse and select .pdf file."
    Exit Sub
End If

LastRow = .Range("B9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Last Row
PDFFile = .Range("O2").Value 'File Name
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PDFFile
Application.Wait Now + 0.00006

CustRow = .Range("O4")
Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True 'move to next field in .pdf
Application.SendKeys "^(c)", True 'copy
Application.Wait Now + 0.00006
AppActivate "Excel" 'return to Excel
Application.Wait Now + 0.00006
ActiveSheet.Range("E" & CustRow).Select
Application.Wait Now + 0.00006
Application.SendKeys "^(v)", True 'paste
Application.Wait Now + 0.001

End With
End Sub
```

So when I run this, the programme works until it has to paste in the Excel cell (which it has selected). When I Esc out of the process, it actually pastes the text into the VBA module. So what is stopping Excel from accepting the command?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Luckily for you this question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36270247/extract-data-from-pdf-and-add-to-worksheet) and there is already a few answers there that should help you solve this issue.

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately the thread you linked had no answer beyond utilising 3rd party programme like Adobe which I do not have acces too. I have developed some code that does the trick, though it does not 'paste' at the end. I will paste the code above.

Comment: What about this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49341685/5958842

Comment: I am sorry, but it requires ByteScout and I would prefer a solution that only uses Excel VBA and Adobe Acrobat Reader (free version).

Comment: Sorry, I meant this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343855/5958842