# visual basic .net continue application

Tags: vb.net, continue

I just stat to study visual basic .net

I would like to ask about how to continue application.

For example

```
    Private Sub UI_BT_SAVE_STOP_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UI_BT_STOP.Click
    Stop
End Sub
```

then , application will stop on the middle of processing(like a stop button on the visual studio)

I was trying to make continue button, but I can not find continue function to change my application status from stop to continue.

is there anyway to continue application again ?

thanks

Comment: Stop is a debugger command. Why would you want to continue programmatically?

Comment: i sometimes want to stop the application during running the application.

Comment: Make a loop with Thread.Sleep(10) call loop like this `while Not isRunning Thread.Sleep(10) End While` add this in other code when you press stop button just make `isRunning = false` and start button make `isRunning = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing quite like that but you could always try importing the sleep function, seen here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/469358/1504882

This will suspend everything the application is doing though.