# word vba: webbrowser not navigating for ReadyState to check

Tags: vba, webbrowser-control, ms-word

I am trying to extract links from webpages, but it seems webbrowser does not navigate, so I get infinite loop at webbrowser1.readstate <> readystate_complete...

HOWEVER, if make a breakpoint at webbrowser1.readstate <> readystate_complete, the webbrowser navigates successfully in the userform, and code works....

Any ideas? Thanks

```
Do Until n = num

    WebBrowser1.Navigate URL

    Do While WebBrowser1.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    Loop


    If WebBrowser1.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Then
        'code
    end if

    n = n +1

loop
```

Comment: found a solution, don't use webbrowser, use the internet explorer application, see http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/excel-vba/automate-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while` loop you use in your question and in your answer is a [busy waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) tight loop, consuming CPU cycles in vain while waiting for something to happen. It works (sort of) for `InternetExplorer` object, because the latter runs in its own separate process. It doesn't work for in-process `WebBrowser` control, because your loop doesn't pump Windows messages, which is required for navigation to work. If you want to stick with the loop approach, consider placing [Sleep 250](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469358/1768303) and [DoEvents](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/118468) calls inside your loop to mitigate busy waiting and pump messages. This is still [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352301/how-to-use-doevents-without-being-evil), instead you should consider re-factoring your code to use [`WebBrowser_DocumentComplete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768329(v=vs.85).aspx) event.

Comment: Thanks. The DocumentComplete method seemed to be the standard, but I needed a way to keep all my code in one subroutine, since it loops to before the IE/webbrowser is called and uses stored data from before calling.