# Excel VBA and Google Maps

Tags: excel, google-maps-markers, vba

I'm developing an application in Excel VBA and I need a way for Google Maps to capture my location automatically (without me having to enter my address). Is this possible through Excel VBA?

Comment: You can try opening Google Maps via IE and then navigate the button with ID: `id="widget-mylocation"` (it's the bottom right one).

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you're still using stackoverflow! When working with google maps I found a quick little URL trick you can use. You can use the URL to setup directions or just automatically track your location.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/my+location/
```

This link will automatically upon load, generate a new link (google maps works by loading tons of Div blocks so every section has a generated URL) of your address.

If you want to use the link for directions try the following

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/my+location/Secondary address goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that automatic.  I just ran the following snippet of vba that was part of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600586/excel-vba-create-an-embededed-webbrowser-and-use-it) to get a web browser embedded on a worksheet and have found it somewhat finicky but it does eventually work  (as per what's shown in the code you need 2 sheets before you run & if it doesn't work you'll have to delete the web browser object and rerun).  There are extensive examples available on how to add markers to maps shown on this web browser object (here's [one](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/getmaps/mapmarkers))

```
 Sub AddWebBroswerToWorksheet()

    Dim myWebBrowser
    Dim wb, doc, x As Long

    Sheet2.Activate

    Set myWebBrowser = Sheet1.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Shell.Explorer.2", _
                       Left:=147, Top:=60.75, Width:=300, Height:=200)

    Set wb = myWebBrowser.Object
    With wb
         .Navigate "about:blank"
         .Document.Open "text/html"
         For x = 1 To 100
           .Document.write "init<br>"
         Next x
         .Document.Close
         .Document.body.Scroll = "no"
    End With

    Sheet1.Activate

    wb.Navigate "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=49.2827,-123.1207"

End Sub
```

From there you should be able to interact with it via vba to show markers placed on an appropriate web site.  In other words it would take a bit of development to get what you want.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer does not match my question. I'm already using google api to open google maps. I just need a way to automatically capture my current position in it

Comment: You can just change the url string accordingly to show your latitude and longitude as per the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your attempt, but I believe you did not understand my problem exactly: I only want a way for Google Maps to inform me of my position by inserting this information into the sheet of the excel worksheet. However, I want it to do this automatically, that is, without first needing to inform my position

Comment: Additional note: When I open google maps in my PC's browser, a marker will automatically appear in my location. It is this location that I want to capture through vba excel

Comment: If excel can capture the return url then you might be able to get a hold of that. I have no idea of whether it can or can't.

Comment: OK. I think for now this is not possible with VBA eXCEL. Thank you very much for your attention. Strong hug

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 Sub GoogleMaps()
   Dim ie As Object
   Dim url As String
   Dim Location

   url = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/my+location"

   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   With ie
   .Visible = True
   .navigate url
        .Top = 5
        .Left = 5
        .Height = 1300
        .Width = 1900
       While ie.readyState <> 4

    Wend

    While ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
End With
  Set ie = Nothing
   End with
 End Sub
```

Remember, that what the @MercPls mentioned in the answer above it's a permalink. You can modify it depending on what certainly you need. If you are interested in the different locations or sth you can parse this permalink with some Excel cell values.