# ie.busy not working well [VBA]

Tags: internet-explorer, vba

I am using :

```
While ie.busy
DoEvents
Wend

' Some Code
```

To add a pause in my code, while internet explorer refreshes. But this doesnt seem to be working well. The 'Some code part is getting executed pre-maturely and throwing an error.

I have tried using other methods as well. for e.g.

```
Errorhandler:

While ie.busy
DoEvents
Wend

On Error Goto Errorhandler
'Some Code
```

But even this isnt working and sometimes the code is esecuted pre maturely.

Please suggest an infallible alternative to ie.busy

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19019200/1768303) for how to handle a busy waiting loop.  You should not be checking only against `.busy`, but also against `ReadyState = 4 'Complete`.

Answer (score 5):

In our code, ie.Busy (InternetExplorer.Application Object) is not very credible. Here is what we use and works:

```
Enum READYSTATE
    READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
    READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
    READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
    READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
    READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum

Dim strUrl
Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'....
' do navigation...
'
strUrl = "http://www.example.com/"
ie.Navigate strUrl

'
' waiting for the ie complete loading:
'
Do While (ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE)
  DoEvents
Loop

'
' here below you do stuffs on the new loaded URL:
'
```

You can try.

Comment: This is not a complete answer unless you also provide code for the WinAPI sleep function :)

Comment: @David Zemens, Yes this is a good remark. I revised my answer.

Comment: One can comment the usage of sleep() if bothered to use DLL API function.

Comment: @David Zemens, I tested again, it's more reactive ignoring Sleep(). So revised again.