# Vba getElementById cause Run-time error '424'

Tags: html, vba, button, web-scraping

Really appreciate if anyone can help.
The part of code always run into Run - time Error:

[image]

The HTML part is in the picture:

[image]

Thanks for attention.

```
Sub HTML_Table_To_Excel()
    Dim objIE As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate ("http://www.global-rates.com/interest-rates/libor/libor.aspx")
    End With
    While objIE.Busy
    Wend
    
    Dim HTMLDoc As Object
    Set HTMLDoc = objIE.document
    
    Dim EuroButton As Object
    Set EuroButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("btn_eur")
    
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
......
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line does it fail on?  If you put a break on that line and wait a couple of seconds before continuing execution, does it still fail?

Comment: @TimWilliams Set EuroButton = .....  This line fails. And thanks,Tim, if I put a break point there, and wait for a while, the sub doesn't fail.

Comment: I think you need to extend your `While IE.Busy` check: see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334880/ie-busy-not-working-well-vba

Answer (score 0):

It's not an element ID - it's a tag name; `Set EuroButton = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("btn_eur")` then when you need to order it: `EuroButton(0).[command here]`

Answer (score 0):

You were just fine with your selector. It does have that id. The problem is you need a proper wait for page load before attempting to click. Try the below. I have also updated to .navigate2 and removed the unnecessary ().

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub HtmlTableToExcel()
    Dim objIE As Object, HTMLDoc As Object, euroButton As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.global-rates.com/interest-rates/libor/libor.aspx"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set HTMLDoc = .document
        Set euroButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("btn_eur")
        euroButton.Click
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
         Stop '<==delete me later
        '-----
        '.Quit
    End With
End Sub
```