# Getting the ReadyState of an XmlHttpRequest from Javascript in VBA

Tags: javascript, ajax, vba, excel

I have an Excel file that we keep for things we find around my job.

We have to log into a website in order to check certain things. With VBA, I've gotten an IE window to open, I get it to log in to the website and fill out a form (and submit it!).

However, my problem arises because the form is submitted using Javascript and AJAX. So, I can therefore not get the response data that comes out (which is what I started this whole endeavor for).

**My question is thus:** is there *any* way I can loop in VBA until the Javascript XML object gets the data, or am I totally insane for trying?

Edit: due to a request, I am putting the code I have currently. I cannot post both the items that say [removed] due to our privacy agreement. I know for a fact that once the response data is loaded it is appended to a div that has an ID of "resultsTable" However, my attempts to loop until that DOM element was found did not work.

**EDIT #2** I finally got something working. What was going wrong in my original code was I didn't know how the ohtml.getElementById() function worked and what it returned if it found nothing. The following waits until the data set appears. It then does certain actions with the data (which I can't post, unfortunately). Thanks everyone!

## Code

```
Private Sub IE_Autiomation()
    Dim i As Long, r As Range
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer, ohtml As HTMLDocument
    Dim ouser As HTMLInputElement, opass As HTMLInputElement, otext As HTMLTextAreaElement, otable As HTMLTable
    
    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    
    Set r = Application.Union(ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Range, ActiveSheet.ListObjects(2).Range, ActiveSheet.ListObjects(3).Range, ActiveSheet.ListObjects(4).Range)
    Debug.Print r.Address

    Set r = Application.Intersect(r, ActiveSheet.Range("B:B,E:E,H:H")) 'Just Trust Me, Ok?
    
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

 
    ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
    IE.Navigate "[Removed]"
    
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Set ohtml = IE.document
    Set ouser = ohtml.getElementById("USER")
    Set opass = ohtml.getElementById("PASSWORD")
    ouser.Value = "[removed]"
    
    
    pw = InputBox("Password?")
    opass.Value = pw
    IE.Visible = True
    ouser.form.submit
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Set otext = ohtml.getElementsByName("vin").Item(0)
    For Each e In r
        If e.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" And Not e.Value = "" Then
            otext.Value = otext.Value & e.Value & ", "
        End If
    Next
        Debug.Print otext.Value
        otext.Value = Left(otext.Value, Len(otext.Value) - 2)
        Debug.Print otext.Value
    
    Debug.Print "So far, wafles."
    
    For Each j In ohtml.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If j.Value = "Submit" Then
            Set ouser = j
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ouser.Click 
    'Here is where I need to wait for the response to load into the HTML
    
    ' Wait while IE loading...
    
    ' Clean up

    Set otable = ohtml.getElementById("resultsTable")
    
    Do While otable Is Nothing
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Set otable = ohtml.getElementById("resultsTable")
    Loop
    
    'IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set ohtml = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing
 
    Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: If you know how long it's likely to take from timings you could use VBA's built-in Timer, or the Sleep API

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469347/is-there-an-equivalent-to-thread-sleep-in-vba

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. The script I'm accessing sometimes is almost immediate and sometimes takes up to 3 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

Use a ready waiting loop.

You will need the WinAPI sleep function:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) 'For use in timer function
```

Then, after your request is sent you need to do something like (example for an IE object, if you update your Q with your code I can modify for your needs).

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "http://google.com"
Do While Not IE.readyState = 4
    Sleep 250
Loop
```

What this does is sleep for 1/4 of a second, looping until the document has loaded.