# Issue logging into website using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to log into a website automatically, and every time I do, I get the "Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed" error.  The site is intranet and it will most likely not be accessable, however, I will provide the code that I am looking at.

It's using java and html, the names are the same and the ID names are the same.  I've tried using the exact name and I've also tried using wildcards, it still gives me the above error.  I've also tried using NAMEs and IDs, neither seem to work for me.

```
HTML Code

<TD class=style6><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt" id=ContentPlaceHolder1_Label1 class=style1>VZID:</SPAN> 
<BR><INPUT style="WIDTH: 125px" id=ContentPlaceHolder1_userid class=text name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$userid> 
<BR><SPAN style="FONT-SIZE: 9pt" id=ContentPlaceHolder1_Label2 class=style1>Password:</SPAN> 
<BR><INPUT style="WIDTH: 125px" id=ContentPlaceHolder1_password class=text name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$password value="" type=password> 
<BR><BR><INPUT id=ContentPlaceHolder1_submitthis class=button name=ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$submitthis value=Login type=submit> </TD>
```

This is the Scripting:

```
                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Label1" class="style1" style="font-size:9pt;">VZID:</span>
                            <br />
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$userid" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_userid" class="text" style="width:125px;" />  

                            <br />

                <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Label2" class="style1" style="font-size:9pt;">Password:</span>
                            <br />
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$password" type="password" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_password" class="text" style="width:125px;" />   

                            <br />
                            <br />
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$submitthis" value="Login" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_submitthis" class="button" />    
                        </td>
                        <td>
```

Finally, here is the code that I am working from in VBA as of my last attempt to make it work:

```
Sub sbIE_OpenVMOSite()

    uname = "username"
    pword = "password"
    fdUSERNAME = "*usename*"
    fdPASSWORD = "*password*"
    fdSUBMIT = "*submitthis*"
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    WebSite = "Thewebsite"

    Dim IE As Object
    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
    IE.Navigate "http://ccssid.verizon.com/login.aspx"
    ' Wait while loading...
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
    Loop
        IE.Visible = True
    'Release Set
    'IE = Nothing

    'On Error Resume Next
    IE.document.getElementById(fdUSERNAME).Value = uname      'Enters Username
    IE.document.getElementById(fdPASSWORD).Value = pword  'Enters Password

    IE.document.all(fdSUBMIT).Click

End Sub
```

Thanks for any help

****EDIT****

So I tried modifying the delay and not I get an interface not known error lol...

```
Sub sbIE_OpenVMOSite()

    uname = "username"
    pword = "password"

    myWebsite = "TheWebsite"
    fdUSERNAME = "ContentPlaceHolder1_userid"
    fdPASSWORD = "ContentPlaceHolder1_password"
    fdSUBMIT = "ContentPlaceHolder1_submitthis"

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate myWebsite
    IE.Visible = True
        'Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
    'Do While IE.Busy
    '    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
    'Loop
    'Wend

    Do
        If IE.readyState = 4 Then
            IE.Visible = False
            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop


    'MsgBox ("POP")
    IE.document.getElementByID(fdUSERNAME).Value = uname  'Enters Username
    IE.document.getElementByID(fdPASSWORD).Value = pword  'Enters Password
    IE.document.all(fdSUBMIT).Click

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this! I corrected fdUSERNAME (and fdPASSWORD and fdSUBMIT while I was at it, but they might not have caused any issues the way they were). Also, I cleaned the code up a little bit.

```
Sub sbIE_OpenVMOSite()

    uname = "username"
    pword = "password"

    myWebsite = "http://TheWebsite"
    fdUSERNAME = "ContentPlaceHolder1_userid"
    fdPASSWORD = "ContentPlaceHolder1_password"
    fdSUBMIT = "ContentPlaceHolder1_submitthis"    

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate myWebsite
    IE.Visible = True

    While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
    Wend

    IE.document.getElementById(fdUSERNAME).Value = uname      'Enters Username
    IE.document.getElementById(fdPASSWORD).Value = pword  'Enters Password    
    IE.document.all(fdSUBMIT).Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and I get the same error, I tried to use the actual values too, for both getElementById and getElementByName, and then the wildcard search that I had on my original posting, but it still comes back with "Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed"

Comment: Maybe your page isn't done loading. Sometimes the computer gets to the `While IE.Busy` part before having started loading; try adding a `msgbox "pop!"` right before inputting the values. Also, if the page contains frames, you have to use `IE.Document.Frames(x).getElement...`; in VBA, each frame acts as a document of its own (from my understanding).

Comment: No Frames, The only thing that I noticed when I added the msgbox, I adjusted the "delay" but it didn't really pause like it should have...  it could be that the site isn't done opening up yet

Comment: To know whether or not the `While IE.Busy` is causing the problem, replace the entire loop by `Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 10, Now)` (or any value high enough to ensure the website IS completely loaded).  Getting a good "sleep" function sometimes require fine tuning.

Comment: Sorry I was off the last few days... I went back and looked, the "timer" is the same as you mentioned, but it's like it's being ignored.  it doesn't delay anything really, and as soon as the webpage loads, it gives the "Method 'Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed" error.  The page has CSS and Java encoded too, do you think that might be causing an issue?

Comment: [Use the WinAPI sleep function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23616808/1467082) instead of Application.Wait?  It is usually more reliable than `Application.Wait`.

Comment: Thank you, David, I used the function you suggested.  It seems to do more, but now it returns a different error, "The object invoked has disconnected from it's clients."  I am starting to think that I won't be able to make a webscraper from this site lol, I haven't even figured out the rest of the logistics, I can't even get VBA to log in lol...