# Pause Outlook for a given amount of time

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to run Outlook code 10 seconds after an email is received.

I tried using `application.wait` but it appears that you cannot do this with Outlook.

How do I pause Outlook for a given amount of time?

Comment: Is it 32 or 64-bit Office?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a Sub that will mimic the `Application.Wait`, something like.

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
'For 64-Bit
'Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Sub Pause(intSeconds As Variant)
  ' Comments: Waits for a specified number of seconds
  ' Params  : intSeconds      Number of seconds to wait
  ' Source  : Total Visual SourceBook

On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

    Dim datTime As Date
    datTime = DateAdd("s", intSeconds, Now)
    Do
        ' Yield to other programs (better than using DoEvents which eats up all the CPU cycles)
        Sleep 100
        DoEvents
    Loop Until Now >= datTime
PROC_EXIT:
    Exit Sub

PROC_ERR:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & ". " & Err.Description, , "Pause Method"
    Resume PROC_EXIT
End Sub
```

To call this you could use `Pause 3`

Comment: For some reason it isn't letting me use the sleep function either so that's a no go. Any ideas why it is doing this?

Comment: You might need to include the library to the sleep function. Try the edited code.

Comment: Perfect, it didn't work before you edited the code but it does now. Thank you very much. May I ask what the issue was?

Comment: Windows provides an API function named `Sleep` that suspends the current process thread. Without including the declaration the compiler does not know what to do with Sleep. First I did not include the explicit declaration of the Sleep function. Now that we have added it, it works.

Comment: But where did the "Wait" go to?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the need for complicated function..

Try This:

```
#If VBA7 Then
'Code is running VBA7 (2010 or later).

     #If Win64 Then
     'Code is running in 64-bit version of Microsoft Office.
      Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
     #Else
     'Code is running in 32-bit version of Microsoft Office.
      Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
     #End If

#Else
'Code is running VBA6 (2007 or earlier).

#End If

Sub Test()
 Debug.Print Now
 Sleep 10000
 Debug.Print Now
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way:

```
    T0 = Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")
    Do Until Now > T0
    Loop
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea, this is a [busy wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), you should put some [sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469347/is-there-an-equivalent-to-thread-sleep-in-vba) there.

Answer (score 0):

Throw a DoEvents in this and it'll be okay

```
T0 = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

Do Until Now > 10

  DoEvents

Loop
```

Comment: What type is T0? I wonder why so many people use implicit types...

Comment: It's variant here, but in general, it should be a `date`.  I was suggesting this for the insert into what @procpy wrote.