# VBA Selenium Wait Query for manual intervention to verify login

Tags: excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have to write an automated programme in VBA selenium for Langify website which is also an extension for shopify to translate the text in to another language. I have an excel sheet with two columns, and I want to open the browser using selenium till entering email address, then a manual intervention is required to type password and verification code after which selenium should start executing rest of the code to add the form and save data one by one.

Is it possible in selenium vba to wait for 30-45 seconds in between the execution of code for any manual intervention?

```
Option Explicit
Dim driver As New Selenium.WebDriver


Sub langify()

Dim webpage As String
Dim shopifypage As String
Dim login As String
Dim password_ As String
Dim FindBy As New Selenium.By
Dim keys As New Selenium.keys



driver.Start "chrome"
driver.Get "https://v2.langify-app.com/"


shopifypage = Sheet3.Range("H2").Text 'rtuaeplus.myshopify.com
login = Sheet3.Range("H3").Text 'xyz@testemail.com
password_ = Sheet3.Range("H4").Text 'password

AppActivate ("CHROME")


driver.FindElementById("form_shop_url").Click shopifypage
driver.FindElementById("form_install").Click
driver.FindElementByCss("#account_email").SendKeys login

'wait for manual intervention for below code.

**'next step click on continue with email button,
'then enter the password using below code
driver.FindElementByCss("#account_password", 150000).SendKeys password_
'then continue button
'enter verification code**
'continue executing the code

'click on custom navigation button
'click on global button
'add 3 dots at the right side 
'select add new customer content
'choose first box and copy the text in first cell of first row 
'save the data
'repeat by clicking on 3 dots until data till last row will be added to the site.



End Sub
```

Comment: Check if this solution helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469347/is-there-an-equivalent-to-thread-sleep-in-vba

Comment: By the way, why do you need manual intervention?

Comment: First, i am not able to find the element which can click the button after entering email and password. 

Second for first time or second time users have to enter google authentication code after password button click

Comment: I need to learn how to find element properly. :(

Comment: "<button class="ui-button ui-button--primary ui-button--full-width ui-button--size-large  captcha__submit" type="submit" name="commit" data-disable="true" data-bind-disabled="captchaDisabled" define="{localClass: new CaptchaStateHandler($context, {
                            v2Completed: true,
                            v3EnterpriseCompleted: false,
                            formCompleted: true,
                          })}" enable_submit_onload="true">Continue with Email</button>
this is the string from where i have to find the element to click on buttomn"

Comment: from above string I have to find the element to click on button